# How to repass a modified bundle back to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, illegalstateexception

I have a fragment to which I pass data through a bundle. It does some processes and sends to other fragments. After that there is 2nd set of data  has to be sent back to the first fragment. How can this be done?

The following code gives the error:
"IllegalStateException: Fragment already active at android.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:696)". So there is a problem in the way the bundle is recreated. What is the correct method to do this?

Code in the activity:  It passes two rows of two nested arraylists to fragments and starts the first fragment.

```
  private void changeExercise(int x){
    if(x < list.size()) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("ex_list", list.get(x));
        bundle.putStringArrayList("ex_data", exercise_data.get(x));
        //All fragments use the same data passed from activity using the bundle
        preExerciseFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        //1st fragment used if !exercise_data.get(x).get(2).equals("bbb") after replacing previous
        exerciseFragment.setArguments(bundle);// 2nd fragment used  after replacing previous
        postExerciseFragment.setArguments(bundle);//3rd fragment used  after replacing previous
        feedbackFragment.setArguments(bundle); //Then 4th fragment used  after replacing previous

        if (!exercise_data.get(x).get(2).equals("bbb")) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.workout_layout, preExerciseFragment, "preexercise").commit();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.workout_layout, exerciseFragment, "exercise").commit();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Workout is over for the day!! Good job!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Code in 4th fragment (FeedbackFragment) through an interface:

```
//
ex_num++;
//
changeExercise(ex_num);
```

This calls the changeExercise method in the activity. Now the next two rows of the two arraylists in the activity should be passed to the fragment through the bundle. This setArguments method is giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to pass data between fragments as a bundle (if they are both active at the same time).

have setters in both fragments that can assign an instance of each other (you can make these interfaces if you want) and then have `preExerciseFragment.setPost(postExerciseFragment)` and `postxerciseFragment.setPre(preExerciseFragment);` where you  'setArguments'.

Then both fragments can talk directly through method passes, no need to pack&pass data back and forth inside a bundle.

This is: less code, cleaner, and more efficient since you don't have to create extra bundle objects

Comment: I am passing the data from the activity to the fragments. I was not sufficiently clear while framing the question. I am sorry. Now I have edited the question to make it easier to understand.

Would it still be better to send data from activity through an interface to the fragments? As I am doing this process multiple times.

Comment: unless you are changing activities, then you shouldn't use a bundle. (that is what 'bundle' is for) if you are staying within the same activity, then you should use the above method.